# Java with TestNG lose initialized variable

Tags: java, testng

There is surprising situation, which I can't understand. I have test automation with RestAssured (pet project). I want to prepare `RequestSpecification spec` variable in `@BeforeSuite` method, in parent class. Then I want to use `spec` variable in tests of child class. Here is code of parent class

```
public class BaseTest {

private String baseUrl = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/";
protected RequestSpecification spec;

@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite() {
    String apiKey = System.getProperty("api_key");
    spec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .setBaseUri(baseUrl)
            .addHeader("x-api-key", apiKey)
            .addFilter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())
            .addFilter(new RequestLoggingFilter())
            .addFilter(new AllureRestAssured())
            .build();
    }
}
```

And here is a test in child class'

```
public class OurLittleTest extends BaseTest {

@Test
public void test() {
    //1
    String id = Breeds.search(spec, "Scottish Fold").then().extract().body().jsonPath().get("[0].id");
```

problem is that `spec` variable in test is null, while I was waiting it won't be null...

Why it happens? Why `spec` is null ?

I've recordered a [screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/P09FP4Mua9wv) where you can see my problem

**UPDATE**
Everything is fine with Junit 5. The `spec` variable is not null in child classes anymore. So here are me `build.gradle` files:

With TestNG:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.8.1"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.qameta.allure' version '2.8.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

allure {
    configuration = 'testImplementation'
    version = '2.7.0'
    allureJavaVersion = '2.7.0'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.5'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    implementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.4.0'
    implementation group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-rest-assured', version: '2.14.0'
    implementation "io.qameta.allure:allure-testng:2.14.0"
    testImplementation group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '7.3.0'
}

test {
    useTestNG() {
        parallel = 'methods'
        threadCount = 2
    }
    if (project.hasProperty("api_key")) {
        systemProperties.put("api_key", "$api_key")
    }
}
```

With Junit 5:

```
plugins {
    id 'io.qameta.allure' version '2.5'
    id 'java'
}

allure {
    configuration = 'testImplementation'
    version = '2.7.0'

    useJUnit5 {
        version = '2.7.0'
    }

}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.5'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    implementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.4.0'
    implementation group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-rest-assured', version: '2.14.0'
    implementation group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-junit5', version: '2.14.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform{
        systemProperty 'junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default'         , 'per_class'
        systemProperty 'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled',              'true'
        systemProperty 'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default',         'same_thread'
        systemProperty 'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default', 'concurrent'
    }
    if (project.hasProperty("api_key")) {
        systemProperties.put("api_key", "$api_key")
    }
}
```

What's wrong with TestNG ?

Comment: Have you tried with the latest testng version?

Comment: I'm using version: '7.3.0'

Comment: I assume you are using Android studio. So maybe an issue with the plugin (Since this is working without any issues in Eclipse). Have you tried to run using `xml` suite file ?

Comment: No, I'm not using Android studio. Just RestAssured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is usage of `@BeforeSuite`. It is meant to be used only once per suite and ignored in following runs.

For initializing the spec you can either do it directly inline in the field like `protected RequestSpecification spec = new RequestSpecBuilder()...` or use `@BeforeClass`.

Comment: I have just one run. I believe in this case initialized variable in parent class also should be initialized in child classes.

Comment: @IgorVlasuyk: True, in your example there is only one test class, but that does not mean that you have exactly the same BaseTest instance (actually you have two, one with initialized spec field, one without). You can see this in your screencast: The first breakpoint shows "this = BaseTest@3743"), so the testng framework created via reflection a BaseTest instance which is different to the instance in breakpoint in "this = OurLittleTest@4007"). Thats the reason why spec is null. It is not nullified in between, they are simply two different instances of the BaseTest class.

Comment: The low-level reason for this behaviour can be found in the testng suite runner implementation: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/testng-core/src/main/java/org/testng/SuiteRunner.java#L329. All @BeforeSuite labelled methods are stored in a hashmap, so there is no duplicate and the concrete test runner is filling it. This also explains that this behaviour is influenced by the testrunner impl and "only one test" is a special case. I.e. on my local in eclipse it works but via gradle and for you in IntelliJ the testrunner impl differs and uses different BaseTest instances.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for clarification. But I find such behaviour quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, no error. The problem might be in `OurLittleTest` class you use Junit, and you use testNG in `BaseTest` class

Comment: No, I use @Test from TestNG
`import org.testng.annotations.Test;`

Comment: If you double check and say that, I run out of idea. I've done watching video and and testing your code in my side carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a use case to set a variable only once in base class for all subclass tests, you can use static variable in base class.

Once set in base class it will be available in all sub class tests.